# Need help understanding staging shown in infographic of Titan launch of Hexagon satellites

Tags: launch, launch-vehicle, srb, titan-rocket

The NPR News item [I Spy, Via Spy Satellite: Melting Himalayan Glaciers](https://www.npr.org/2019/06/19/733739909/i-spy-via-spy-satellite-melting-himalayan-glaciers) discusses use of declassified historical satellite images that include glaciers, and link to the newly published and Open Access article in Science [Acceleration of ice loss across the Himalayas over the past 40 years](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/6/eaav7266).

It also links to a short pdf fact sheet on the NRO's website [Hexagon; America's Eye in Space](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/6/eaav7266) which contains the image/infographic below.

I don't understand what's being illustrated for the first stage core and the two side boosters. The two boosters look to be very different from each other and have different names, and I can't figure out where the separation of the first stage of the core separates from the second stage. What is actually happening here?

[image: from NRO's Hexagon; America's Eye in Space]

Comment: It's a poor image. More shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much better diagram (it's for Titan IIIe, but it's the same except for the upper stage, which doesn't feature in the question).

[image]

1. Solid Rocket Motor (SRM) ignition followed by liftoff
2. First stage ignition (trigger event: g-switches)
3. SRM separation (trigger event: timer started by the g-switches)
4. Second stage ignition / stage separation ("fire in the hole" staging) (trigger event: first stage propellant depletion)
5. Payload shroud jettison (trigger event: timer started at first stage shutdown)
6. Second stage shutdown / stage separation (trigger event: guidance system)

(Then the third stage does whatever it does)

[Source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750004937.pdf)

Comment: Yes this is indeed much clearer, thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: fyi "fire in the hole" https://youtu.be/PBkZNMM_IUg found in https://www.reddit.com/r/space/comments/6f8om6/titan_ii_fireinthehole_staging_blasts_part_of_the/ I'd never heard of that before.

Comment: @uhoh recently mentioned here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36818/6944